# ngIf not immediately loading template when false

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a component which will load a Youtube video when true. However, when the ngIf statement evaluates too false the template does not load. The context for the problem is that I'm trying to conditionally render a div when an ad blocker blocks a Youtube video just to let the user know why the content isn't loading rather than having a white box. I have a created a service which returns a Boolean and I am sure that is working. Interestingly when I search for the matching text in the Chrome dev tools elements filter it triggers the template to load.

So far I've tried putting change detection refs into various life cycles. without much luck. I building on a component that was originally written by someone else. It does implement a change detection strategy onPush. I'm unsure if that is creating problems.

```html
<div *ngIf='loadYoutube; else loadError'>
    <iframe [width]="width"
        [height]="height"
        [src]="src | safe:'url'"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen
        class="youtube-player">
    </iframe>
</div>
<ng-template #loadError>
    <p>
      Turn Yo ad blocker off please
    </p>
</ng-template>
```

Currently when loadYouTube evaluates to true it performs as expected. When false a white box appears. As mentioned, when searching keywords from the elements tab of the chrome inspector the template loads.

Comment: Can you please create a Stackblitz for this. Your provided snippet looks fine to me.

Comment: Does `loadYoutube` ever evaluate to false for whichever reasons?

Comment: Load Youtube should evaluate to false when an adblocker is detected. I only just googled what StackBlitz was. Looks very cool. Not 100% comfortable uploading code as it's for a commercial site.

Comment: Try getting rid of the semicolon after loadYoutube.
*ngIf='loadYoutube else loadError'

Comment: I've just tried getting rid of the semicolon same result I'm afraid.

Comment: Remove on push change detection.

Comment: @MatthewMartin what is your angular version?

Comment: @MatthewMartin You don't need to upload the complete code. Just reproduce a minimum version. If you are not able to reproduce your scenario using minimal code, then the root cause might be something else than what you've guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. As per usual the problem was much more simple than originally thought. In a higher level competent there was actually a canvas occupying the same area that text was meant to occupy. Interestingly when key text was searched in chrome element tools it brought text to the front. This made us think it was an angular rendering issue. Just a bit of an Obscure Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

Loadyoutube always has value? You init that in constructor or in ngOnInit?

Y try with default strategy meanwhile, i think onPush can generate problems in your case.